# How to get current date in a specific time zone in Mongodb Aggregate 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to evaluate an aggregate query based on a date condition as in i want a status variable which tells if the system is open or close. If the date,time is over the status is closed else it is open.

I am trying to get current date which i am able to get with new Date(). But how can i convert to a specific timezone. I found dateToString in higher versions of mongodb.

But my db version is 3.2

```
db.getCollection('testCollection').aggregate([
{"$project":{
    "_id":1,
    "startDate":1,
    "endDate":1,
   "currentDate":new Date()
}}
])
```

I am able to get the date but unable to convert it to a timezone.
Is there something like

```
"currentDate":new Date("Asia/Kolkata")
```

Comment: Could you refine the question slightly to make more clear how you want to query the data vs. how you want to format/view it?  In your post it seems you want to query but there is no `$match` in your agg, only `$project`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is older version, you have to do a bit of calculation to convert it to your `timezone`. Below is sample aggregation query where `'x'` is offset between `UTC` and your `timezone` in hours.

```
db.getCollection('testCollection').aggregate([
    {"$project":{
        "_id":1,
        "startDate":1,
        "endDate":1,
        "currentDate":new Date(),
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": {"$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}},
        "month": { "$month": { "$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}},
        "year": { "$year": { "$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}}
        "hour": { "$hour": {"$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}},
        "minute": { "$minute": { "$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}},
        "second": { "$second": { "$add": [ new Date(), x * 60 * 60 * 1000 ]}}
    }}
])
```

Comment: I have timezones in this format only for now and this is a field in the table.. 'America/New_York' or 'Asia/Kolkata'

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.   MongoDB stores, fetches, and queries datetimes strictly in "Z" mode:  milliseconds since epoch GMT.  Any date you insert will be interpreted as a Z date regardless of how your local program may be interpreting it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/ possible in mongo 4

Comment: Caution:  That is the `$dateToString` operator.  It is an outbound-formatting function only.  You cannot directly query using it.   You can do a `$project` and then `$match' on the string output but that cannot take advantage of indexes.